# Wordpress password reset filter message returning blank login

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the [following filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/) to replace the default password reset email. The email sends fine, although when opened the login is missing. The login is added in two of the messages $user_login and as it is returning blank, the password reset url is also not working. Everything else works fine and if I manually add the login the url also is correct.

Any ideas what this could be?

```
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'my_reset_password_message', null, 2);

function my_reset_password_message( $message, $key ) {

    if ( strpos($_POST['user_login'], '@') ) {
        $user_data = get_user_by('email', trim($_POST['user_login']));
    } else {
        $login = trim($_POST['user_login']);
        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
    }

    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;

    $msg = __('The password for the following account has been requested to be reset:'). "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= network_site_url() . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __('If this message was sent in error, please ignore this email.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:');
    $msg .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');


    return $msg;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code -

```
add_filter("retrieve_password_message", "my_custom_password_reset", 99, 4);

function my_custom_password_reset($message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ){
        $message = "Someone has requested a password reset for the following account: " . sprintf(__('%s'), $user_data->user_email) . " If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen. To reset your password, visit the following address: " . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";
         return $message;
 }
```